# How to insert values from one table to another table if that particular value doesn't exists and if exists update value of one column of that row

Tags: mysql, database

How to insert values from one table to another table if that particular value doesn't exists and if exists update value of one column of that row.

I am trying to find distinct rows from one table and store them in another table.
But if that value already exists in the new Table, then i want to add 1 to the count column (eg:: if 1, then 1+1=2).. and if doesn't exists the insert in a row.

Comment: Have a look at the Insert .. on duplicate key update syntax in the manual.

Comment: And combine the above with insert ... select ... and you are done. See the duplicate questions.